# My Mac is invisible to my iPhone on AirDrop

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, airdrop

I want to send a photo from my iPhone (iOS 8) to my Mac (Yosemite) via AirDrop.
Though my iPhone appears on my Mac,
Mac does not appear on iPhone.
How can I fix this?

On both devices, I've selected "Allow me to be discovered by: Everyone".

Comment: Instead of reboot, Is there a real solution to this problem? This, I feel is unacceptable that an Apple Phone running Apple OS cannot send a damn file to another Apple Laptop running Apple OS. Specially when people call them Best Phone & Best Laptop.

Answer (score 4):

I find that when AirDrop stops working even when both devices are within bluetooth range and on the same Wi-Fi network, I often have to reboot both devices. There may be another way, but rebooting both has almost always fixed it. Also of note: if you have any firewall enabled, those settings can interfere as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have had this happen far less while using 10.10.5 and iOS 9.

Comment: I'll also note - interference on set WiFi channels will cause the bluetooth and WiFi discovery process that AirDrop uses to be unreliable. The good news is that the transfer will also be unreliable under that interference, so it's a realistic failure from a system's design standpoint. Think of it like a red light - AirDrop doesn't give you a green light until it can link up under decent or better network conditions.

Comment: @bmike Re:"doesn't give you a green light until it can link up" Unfortunately, it also doesn't give any guidance on how to configure it so that a green light can be given. AirDrop is one of my favorite features when it works, and one of my most hated when it doesn't. Today for me, it's the latter.