# Unable to send files using AirDrop from iPhone to Mac

Tags: iphone, mac, file-sharing, file-transfer, airdrop

I keep seeing this issue where I am unable to send files using AirDrop from iPhone to Mac. The iPhone does not show Macbook when sharing the file through AirDrop.
I have ensured that the `Allow me to be discovered by` is set to `Everyone` on **Mac**, also ensured that `AirDrop` is set to `Everyone` on **iPhone**.

> Macbook Pro - macOS Big Sur 
> iPhone 11 Pro - iOs 15.1

The issue gets resolved when I restart my Macbook. But it keeps happening again and again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Mac is invisible to my iPhone on AirDrop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/203046/my-mac-is-invisible-to-my-iphone-on-airdrop)

Comment: Thanks @fsb, I did mention about rebooting solves the issue, but that's like a workaround and not a solution. I cannot always reboot my mac to send a file.

Comment: In terms of question, may be it is duplicate of what you mentioned but even that one does not have an accepted answer.

Comment: That's all true although it does have 4 upvotes, meaning other found it helpful, and the OP hasn't participated on the site since posting the question so we're not sure if it solved the problem or not.  I thought it was worth a shot.

Comment: Agree, it's helpful and in fact I have mentioned the same thing that if I restart my mac it works. But that's not the desired solution, we don't always restart our machine just to transfer a file rather do it by other means.